Linking different .xcframework based on scheme
I need to integrate 3rd party SDK that was shared to us in a form of 2 .xcframeworks, each for different environment. We are already using 2 Flutter flavors which are mapped to 2 XCode schemes under the hood, named staging and production. How would I link different .xcframework based on scheme?
I tried linking both and then using compiler flag to import only one based on this flag but I can't link both because they use same class names.

If you have two different targets (schemes) of your app you can just simple add a needed xcframework to each of them in your xcode project settings:  <Target> > General > Framework, Libraries and Embedded content.

I tried doing that. I choose staging scheme in top bar and drag&drop the staging framework into Framework, Libraries and Embedded content list. Then I switch to production scheme but the dropped framework is still in the list. And if I now try to drop production framework onto list, nothing happens. No error and dropped items isn't added to the list.

I assume it's something fundamental I'm not getting since I'm completely new to iOS development and it must be something nobody even thought of explaining online. Are are any assumptions that I got wrong?

I think I cracked it. The trick is to link the framework but not embed it,  then copy/embed correct build of framework in "Run script" build phase.
Step by step tutorial:

copy both frameworks to project, each under its own directory. I chose bundle id as names of directories but you can use something else that you are able to pick up during build phase.

Frameworks
  |- Pods_Runner
  |- Pods_RunnerTests
  |- External_framework
    |- bundle.id
      |- ExternalLib
    |- bundle.id.staging
      |- ExternalLib


Don't add any of them to General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content. Table in this section is populated from Build Phases.
Locate Link Binary With Libraries build phase and drag&drop bundle.id.staging/ExternalLib. If you check Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content now, this framework should be listed with Do Not Embed option selected.
Add new "Run script" build phase and paste the code below

PATH_TO_CONFIG=$SRCROOT/External_framework/$PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER/ExternalLib.xcframework
FILENAME_IN_BUNDLE=Frameworks/ExternalLib.xcframework
BUILD_APP_DIR=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app
echo cp $PATH_TO_CONFIG "$BUILD_APP_DIR/$FILENAME_IN_BUNDLE"
cp -R $PATH_TO_CONFIG "$BUILD_APP_DIR/$FILENAME_IN_BUNDLE"


There were some SO answers that helped find the solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34859956/1274643
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216858/1274643

